# "Do to others as yould have them do to you." VS "Do to others as yould EXPECT/WISH them do to you."

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

**"Do to others as you would have them do to you."**

I understand the sentence means *"Do to others as you **would like/wish/expect** them to do to you"*, which perfectly sits well with politeness.

But the sentence uses a causative structure ***"....have them do to you"***, which implies more strength than **"a wish/a want/an expectation"**. And we know this structure is used usually when you arrange someone to do something for you, because maybe you paid, or asked, or persuaded the other person to do it." such as **"I had a plumber repair my tap".**

Shortly, **"...have them do.."** has the same meaning as **to get someone to do something**, whereas the meaning should be **"to expect/wish someone to do something".**

So, I wonder why the sentence uses a causative structure rather than using a softer structure by using one of these words: "**"Do to others as yould wish/want/expect them do to you."**

Comment: **Yould** isn't a word - it's **you would**, or in casual speech **you'd**.

Comment: Good question, but *You would have* is not causative here like *have a plumber*. Only a wish as you say. I'll have you know, I'll have the tofu, not I'll have you thrown out.

Comment: @KateBunting, sorry it is a typing error. I edited it. Thanks.

Comment: @YosefBaskin, Thanks for the answer. I did not know that "...you would have them do..." is not a causative structure but a wish. I think this is something unknown to most learners and the non-native speakers, as this usage is not taught at schools. Now I understand why the sentence did not sit well in my mind when I read it. Today, I am glad I learnt something new.

Comment: The original thing is: Do unto others as you would have them do unto you.